# python - Append to text file on new line

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to add a line into config.dat (addtofile section).  This works once, as soon as I attempt to add a secondline here it fails.

```
raise SameFileError("{!r} and {!r} are the same file".format(src, dst))
shutil.SameFileError: 'backup/file1' and '/home/admin/Documents/backup/file1' are the same file
```

Code is complaining about the above:
Any suggestions.

```
def read_config(data):
    try:
        dest = '/home/admin/Documents/backup/'
        # Read in date from config.dat
        data = open(data)
        # Interate through list of files '\n'
        filelist = data.read().split('\n')
        # Copy through interated list and strip white spaces and empty lines
        for file in filelist:
            if file:
                shutil.copy(file.strip(), dest)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        logger.error("Config file not found")
        print ("Config File not found")


def addtofile(add_config):
    try:
        with open('config.dat', 'a') as file:
            file.write(add_config + "\n")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        logger.error("error message")
        print ("error message here")

args = vars(parser.parse_args())
read = read_config(args['configfile'])
add = addtofile(args['add'])
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've opened the file in read-only (default) mode.  It's still open when you try to open it for appending.  Close the file once you've read the data, and *then* you can write to it.

Comment: Did notice that... Thanks